# Is a 4-byte char just as efficiently used as a key column in an index as a 4-byte int in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, indexing

I know that the byte-size of the key column on your index matters. And that having a 16 byte key column is going to require more page reads during a scan or traverse than having a 4-byte key column.

But does the data *type* matter?

If I have a 4-byte char, can that be just as efficiently indexed as a 4-byte int? I realize that you're going to have a lot more value possibilities with the int and that in that sense, the int is better. But if I have the same number of 4-byte ints and 4-byte chars in two different indexes, are both going to be just as efficient?

Comment: A `varchar(4)` column uses 2-6 bytes - depending on how many characters you store. `Int` is **always** exactly 4 bytes. But the `varchar` - being a *variable-length* column - is typically **less effective** than a fixed-width column like `int`.

Comment: But if it's a **fixed-length**, always 4 character string - by all means, use `char(4)` (instead of `varchar(4)`) !! That'll be much more efficient - just like an `int`, it's fixed-length, and always 4 bytes! If all your `varchar(4)` are always storing 4 characters - those are all 6 bytes each (and carry the "varying length" overhead, in addition)

Comment: Point taken. I've just changed it to char in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

`Int` is better, because with `char(n)` you'll be comparing one char at a time, and unless you `collate Latin1_General_BIN` then you'll also be doing a transformation when comparing chars.

Comment: Do you have any documentation or reference I can read for more information on "comparing one char at a time"? How do you know that it works like that? I'm interested in what you say regarding the transformation when comparing chars. Just want to read more about that.